# Charge inside a shell

Tags: electrostatics

[image]

There's a positive charge Q inside a neutral conducting shell. An external field is applied. I learned that there can be no effect in cavity due to external things (electrostatic shielding), so according to that the net force on Q should be zero, but this is not the case. Why there's a force on Q?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer is this:

You are right that there is no resultant force on Q from the external field E, because it is inside a closed, conductive shell (C), which acts as a [faraday cage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday_cage).

However, even if there was no external electric field E, the charge Q produces its own electric field and that will interact with the conductive shell C. If Q is positive then, if it is not perfectly centered within the shell, the charged particles within the conductive shell will rearrange themselves so that there is a negative charge on the wall closest to Q and a positive charge on the wall furthest from Q. This will set up an electric field that will 'pull' Q towards the wall. So, unless Q is exactly in the center, it will tend to be pulled towards the nearest wall.

As this behavior is all linear, the effects of the external field E and the field produced by Q can be superimposed, so it will still be pulled towards the closest wall of C.

Comment: Will there be a force if there is no electric field?

Comment: Yes, I believe there will be a force even if there is no external field E, because charge Q has its own electric field, which will induce an electric field in the conductive shell. E is a red herring - it won't affect what happens inside the closed shell.

Comment: And what about the charges induced on outer surface of the shell? When they are maintaining electric field inside the metal zero, then why can't they make electric field at Q also zero?

Comment: In the absence of the charge Q, the electric field inside the shell will be zero - the field created by the charges induced on the shell will exactly balance the external electric field E (inside the shell). **But** the charge Q also generates its own electric field, which will induce further charges in the shell, which means the electric field inside the shell will _not_ be zero. The external field E is basically irrelevant to what is happening inside the shell. You could leave it out of the problem and the result will be the same.